# Autoscaling up in Mongo with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, nosql

I am setting up an application connecting to mongoDB with high availability.

I have studied the documentation and setup the replica set successfully through 
`spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:23456/test`

As the application property file is fixed, the application is required to restart if I change the `spring.data.mongodb.uri`.

What if I have a new replica member in mongo, should I need to restart my application with the update in application property?

Or, is it fair enough to use the old configuration? Mongo driver will automatically connect to the new replica member for me with the old configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading properties from the file you need to restart the application once the property is updated.

Otherwise, you need to use some global property management apps like consul which when the properties are changed it will reload the properties value in the application(@RefreshScope).

In your case, once the property is changed you need to disconnect and reconnect to the mongodb by code.

Comment: Does it mean that I have to update the ```spring.data.mongodb.uri``` in order to scale up the number of nodes of mongoDB?